# Try statement doesn't always run?

Tags: c#

i encountered an error "Use of unassigned variable 'attempt'" when i run the code below, i don't understand the reason because as i understand the `try` statement block always runs so the variable should be assigned by the user ? Or am i wrong ? If anyone has i fix or work around that would be helpful.

```
static void MagicNumber(int rndMin, int rndMax, int lives = 4)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int rndNum = rnd.Next(rndMin, rndMax);
    int attempt;
    do
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Remaining lives : {lives}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Enter a number between {rndMin} and {rndMax} :");
            attempt = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error : Enter a number !");
        }
    } while ((lives > 0) || (attempt < rndMin) || (attempt > rndMax));
}

MagicNumber(1, 40, 5);
```

Comment: What happens if `Console.WriteLine` throws an exception?

Comment: It's probably `Console.Readline` that's throwing the exception before the attempt variable has been assigned.

Comment: @Eduardomacedo this is a compile-time error, not runtime. It's thrown for the `attempt` variable inside the `while` clause.

Comment: @gunr2171 oh! yes, you're correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `attempt` will not get assigned a value if an exception gets thrown in your `try` block, so will be unassigned when it gets to the evaluation in your `while`. The two possible solutions are:

1. Initialize it to a default value when you declare it.
2. Assign it some value in your `catch` block.

Either one should work.

Comment: Thank you, i tried you're second suggestion and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

An exception can be thrown in the `try` block prior to setting a value for `attempt`.  You handle the exception so it's then possible for `attempt` to be referenced before being assigned a value.

Best practice is to always assign an initial value to variables.